# Calculating tsrange based on parent/child created dates

Tags: postgresql

Given the table:

```
CREATE TABLE node (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    created timestamp without time zone NOT null,
    path ltree NOT null UNIQUE
);
```

And the records:

```
INSERT INTO node (id, path, created)
VALUES
  (1, '1', '2010-01-01 12:00'),
  (2, '1.2', '2010-01-01 13:00'),
  (3, '1.2.3', '2010-01-01 14:00');
```

How do I get the valid range for each node based on the node's created date and its' parent's created date?

For instance, the ranges for the given path `1.2.3` would be:

```
id | path  | valid
------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 |     1 | tsrange('2010-01-01 12:00', '2010-01-01 13:00', '[)')
 2 |   1.2 | tsrange('2010-01-01 13:00', '2010-01-01 14:00', '[)')
 3 | 1.2.3 | tsrange('2010-01-01 14:00', 'infinity', '[)')
```

Comment: You  mean, "based on the node's created date and its' **child's** created date". What if there's more than one immediate child?

Comment: In this case, I always want to specify a specific path, so different immediate children would be different queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was playing around a little more and found a windowing function that I think might work as well. I'm not sure if it's more or less performant than Laurenz's solution.

```
SELECT
  id, path, tsrange(
    created,
    COALESCE(
      lag(created) OVER (ORDER BY created DESC),
      'infinity'
     )
  ) AS valid
FROM node
WHERE path @> '1.2.3'
ORDER BY path;
```

Latest query:

```
SELECT
    id,
    path,
    tsrange(created, lag(created, -1, 'infinity') OVER (ORDER BY created)) AS valid
FROM
    node
WHERE
    path @> '1.2.3';
```

Comment: You can get rid of the `coalesce()` if you use the three argument version of `lag()` instead: `lag(created, 1, 'infinity') over (...)`

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't know about the parameters! I was able to clean up the query a little bit more by setting the offset to -1.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of a smarter way than a self-join with all nodes that have a `path` just one element longer:

```
SELECT n1.id, n1.path,
       tsrange(n1.created, max(n2.created)) AS valid
FROM node AS n1
   LEFT JOIN node AS n2
      ON n2.path ~ (n1.path::text || '.*{1}')::lquery
GROUP BY n1.id;

 id | path  |                     valid                     
----+-------+-----------------------------------------------
  1 | 1     | ["2010-01-01 12:00:00","2010-01-01 13:00:00")
  2 | 1.2   | ["2010-01-01 13:00:00","2010-01-01 14:00:00")
  3 | 1.2.3 | ["2010-01-01 14:00:00",)
(3 rows)
```